# Should I Allow Asymmetric Equals?

Tags: c#, iequatable, symmetric

I have a C# type for which it makes logical sense to compare for equality with int. Call this type `Number`.

However, I can't make Equals symmetric, because I can't change `Int32.Equals(object other)`. So, should I permit the asymmetric equality, like this:

```
Number numberThree = new Number(3);
int intThree = 3;

bool equal;
equal = numberThree.Equals(intThree); // equal is true
equal = intThree.Equals(numberThree); // equal is false
```

Or should I just only allow equality if the types match as well as the numeric value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It violates the contract of [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47):

> The following statements must be true for all implementations of the `Equals(Object)` method. In the list, `x`, `y`, and `z` represent object references that are not null.
>
> - ...
> - `x.Equals(y)` returns the same value as `y.Equals(x)`.

Anything using `Equals` should be able to depend on that - so violating it could generate some really odd effects. Imagine if `Dictionary<,>.ContainsKey` called `key.Equals(candidateEntry.Key)` but the indexer called `candidateEntry.Key.Equals(key)`... you might see a key as existing, but not be able to fetch the entry... or vice versa. Or maybe it will work in one implementation of `Dictionary<,>`, but not in a subsequent release (or not on Mono, etc).

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the answer. It's a real shame C# doesn't have a built in Number like Java. But yeah, your dictionary example proves it. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: However, you can override the `==` operator just fine. Or use an implicit conversion operator. With either of those, you can ensure that `(a == b) == (b == a)`.

Comment: @Motig: Even if .NET had a `Number` type, that wouldn't remove the requirement to make it symmetric...

Comment: @Luaan: Careful - you can *overload* the operator. And that's what makes it safer than `Object.Equals`, because anything calling your overload (except via reflection) clearly knew about it at compile-time...

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I'm just guessing that if it was built in to the BCL or FCL they would accommodate Equals in the actual number types!

Comment: @Motig: How though? To put it another way - Java has the same requirements for `equals`, and `Integer.equals` returns `false` if you pass it anything other than an `Integer` reference...

Comment: @JonSkeet I assumed that was a byproduct of the primitives in Java not extending from Object. Well, anyway, I don't want to discuss this all day, haha. I'll make it symmetric. :)